# Read creation file date from other users home folders with Python2.7 centOS

Tags: python, centos7, glob

I'm working on a script that will check when the latest backup have been taken by looking at the files creation date.

The files are located on a centOS7 machine in different users home folders.

I'm pretty sure that this has to do with the privileges but everything that I've tried have failed so far.

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import time
import glob
from datetime import date, datetime

date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"

def checkBackup (location, fileName, interval):
    newest = max(glob.iglob(fileName), key=os.path.getctime)
    created = time.strftime('%D', time.localtime(int(os.path.getctime(location+newest))))
    cDate = datetime.strptime(created[:6] + '20' + created[6:], date_format)
    localTime = time.strftime('%D')
    cTime = datetime.strptime(localTime[:6] + '20' + localTime[6:], date_format)
    delta = cTime-cDate

    if delta.days > interval:
            file.write("Missing backup for " + newest + "    ERROR!\n")
    else:
            file.write(newest + " SUCCESSFUL BACKUP\n")
            return;

file = open("backupStatus.txt","w")
checkBackup("/home/user1/","backupFile.gz",30);
checkBackup("/home/user2/","backupFile.gz",30);
file.close()
```

When running this script as user1 I get a new entry in the backupStatus.txt file, but when trying to check the status of the file in the user2's home folder I'm getting and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "checkBackup.py", line 26, in <module>
checkBackup("/home/user2/","backupFile.gz",30);
File "checkBackup.py", line 11, in checkBackup
newest = max(glob.iglob(fileName), key=os.path.getctime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I've added the user1 to the user2 group and thought that this would solve the problem but I'm still getting this error, even when running this as root I'm getting this.

This is my first post in stackoverflow so I hope that I've written this question in the correct way. It's also been a few years since I've done anything with python so feel free to give me tips on how to improve the code!

So, Does anyone have any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Regards

Anton

Comment: `arg is an empty sequence` means that `glob.iglob()` returned no files, so the file is not there.  Your problem might be that you are not including the location in the filename (use `os.path.join`).  Also, something like `os.is_file` might be more appropriate that using `glob`.

Comment: Hi @cdarke     I created 4 new files in the user2 /home all files start with test and called the function like this `checkBackup("/home/user2/","test*",30);` but i still got the same error.

Comment: In the glob in  `checkBackup`, use:  `location + fileName`, you are not adding the directory to the filename, so it is only looking in your current directory.

Comment: @cdarke        I added the location to the file like you said, also tried added it to a new variable before putting it in glob, even tried hardcoding the path to glob like this `newest = max(glob.iglob("/home/newUser/test1.txt"), key=os.path.getctime)` But I'm still getting the same error. I'm going to read a bit about `os.path.join` and  `os.is_file` and see if that might fix the problem

Comment: Works for me, but only if the file exists.  The thing is that you would only ever get a maximum on one filename from your `iglob()`, because it is not a pattern, so why are you using `max()`?

Comment: Maybe you need `/home/user*/backupFile.gz`?

Comment: @cdarke        Backups are being taking from multiple nods in a network and are being sent to this machine in different home folders. I have to say that I'm not the one that designed this I just want to automate its since they are checking the backups manually. the files are being created with the node name+date. so what I want to do is to check all files with that name and get the latest one and see if the backup has been taken within the last 30 days.

Comment: In that case, there should be a pattern where the date appears in the filename.  `*` will probably do it.

Comment: In my original code I have `*` in the filename, I removed it in this example since It still doesn't work even when checking a single file in a other users home folder. this is the file I'm trying to get information from and is located in the newUser's home folder `-rw-rw-r--. 1 user2 user2group 0 Apr 27 10:39 backupFile.gz` I've also added the user1 to user2's group and user permissions `user2:x:1001:user1`  and for the group `user2group:x:1002:user1,user2`

Comment: @cdarke        But you said that it's working for you when running the code, could you share the file permission and if you've added the user1 to user2's group?

Comment: @cdarke        I managed to get it to work! I'll write a summary what was wrong and how the code should have looked. Thanks for the help! I really needed someone to ask questions to to be able to think about it in a different way :)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!  I suggest you put your fixed code (or something close to it) as an answer - it is perfectly OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works.
The reason that it didn't work before was because i only had the glob checking the fileName and not the correct path to it, so it only worked for the files in the same directory.

With help from @cdarke I added the files path to the glob and could successfully get the information from other users /home folders, but after that the next line had an incorrect path (added the path twice to the string), by removing that everything worked as intended.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import time
import glob
from datetime import date, datetime

date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"

def checkBackup (location, fileName, interval):
    newest = max(glob.iglob(location + fileName), key=os.path.getctime)
    created = time.strftime('%D', time.localtime(int(os.path.getctime(newest))))
    cDate = datetime.strptime(created[:6] + '20' + created[6:], date_format)
    localTime = time.strftime('%D')
    cTime = datetime.strptime(localTime[:6] + '20' + localTime[6:], date_format)
    delta = cTime-cDate

    if delta.days > interval:
            file.write("Missing backup for " + newest + "    ERROR!\n")
    else:
            return;

file = open("backupStatus.txt","w")
checkBackup("/home/user1/","backupFile.gz",30);
checkBackup("/home/user2/","backupFile.gz",30);
file.close()
```